# using the -d flag with the read command in Ubuntu via the vagrant provision command

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vagrant, yaml

As part of my provisioning tasks in Vagrant, I am using shyaml to parse a yaml file and create my virtual host files for my various projects.  In my particular case, I am trying to set environment variables.

My yaml file looks like:

```
sites:
    site1:
        ...
        env:
          DB_NAME: example
          DB_USER: root
          DB_PASSWORD: root
          DB_HOST: localhost
          TABLE_PREFIX: www_
```

According to the docs I should this code to grab both the keys and values of mappings:

```
#!/bin/sh

readLine() {
    while [ "$1" ]; do
        IFS=$'\0' read -r -d '' "$1" || return 1
        shift
    done
}

cat 'file.yml' | shyaml key-values-0 sites.site1.env |
while readLine key val; do
  ...
done
```

However, If I run this in Vagrant (Ubuntu 16.04) I get the following error:

```
test.sh: 4: read: Illegal option -d 
close failed in file object destructor: 
sys.excepthook is missing 
lost sys.stderr
```

I have also tried setting the shebang to: `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/usr/bin/env bash` but whenever I ssh into vagrant and `$run sh test.sh` . I'll get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok -  so I have changed the way Vagrant runs the provision script by using the inline provisioning and running the script with /bin/bash.  So: `config.vm.provision :shell, inline: '/bin/bash ' + File.join( 'provision', 'test.sh' )`